# How can I create meaningful OpenSSL error messages?

Tags: c, linux, unix, openssl

I'm implementing a C function to create meaningful error strings when an OpenSSL 1.0.2 function returns with an error.

I'm not that experienced with OpenSSL, and the documentation isn't really helpful, to be honest. Here's my current workflow, but I'm not sure if this is correct:

- Call `SSL_load_error_strings()` during SSL initialization
- Prior to every SSL function call, `ERR_clear_error()` is called
- If an SSL function fails, `SSL_get_error()` is executed
- If the error code returned is `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` or `SSL_ERROR_SSL`, I go on to check the "error queue" by calling `ERR_get_error()`
- Get an error string with `ERR_error_string()` passing in the return value of `ERR_get_error()`
- If `SSL_get_error()` returned `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` I additionally fetch the UNIX error string with `strerror(errno)`

My code basically looks like this:

```c
int error0 = SSL_get_error(ssl, err);
snprintf(msg + strlen(msg), sizeof(msg) - strlen(msg), "SSL_get_error:%d;", error0);

if (error0 == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL || error0 == SSL_ERROR_SSL) {
    int error1 = ERR_get_error();
    if (error1) {
        snprintf(msg + strlen(msg), sizeof(msg) - strlen(msg), " ERR_get_error:%d;%s;", error1, ERR_error_string(error1, NULL));
    }

    if (error0 == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) {
        snprintf(msg + strlen(msg), sizeof(msg) - strlen(msg), " strerror:%s", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

So my question is:

- Is this the correct approach to fetch all related errors?
- The OpenSSL documentation talks about an error queue. Is `ERR_get_error()` supposed to be called multiple times? If so, how do I know when to stop?
- Is it possible to call `ERR_error_string()` with `SSL_get_error()` return values? I did some reasearch on this topic and some say `ERR_error_string()` only works with `ERR_get_error()` return values, while others say the function should also work with `SSL_get_error()` return values as long as `SSL_load_error_strings()` was called before.

**Edit**:

I reread the documentation of `ERR_get_error()`. To get all errors from the queue, I need to repeatedly call `ERR_get_error()` until no more error codes are returned, i.e. until the function returns 0. So I updated my code:

```c
int error0 = SSL_get_error(ssl, err);
snprintf(msg + strlen(msg), sizeof(msg) - strlen(msg), "SSL_get_error:%d;", error0);

if (error0 == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL || error0 == SSL_ERROR_SSL) {
    int error1 = 0;
    while (error1 = ERR_get_error()) {
        snprintf(msg + strlen(msg), sizeof(msg) - strlen(msg), " ERR_get_error:%d;%s;", error1, ERR_error_string(error1, NULL));
    }

    if (error0 == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) {
        snprintf(msg + strlen(msg), sizeof(msg) - strlen(msg), " strerror:%s", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you intend to use errno, you need to save its value before doing any other calls that might change it.

Comment: Errno should never be changed since it's only used in strerror(errno). Am I missing something?